# Openssl can't compile when compiling for ARM, otherwise works fine

Tags: ubuntu, rust, openssl, arm

So recently I have been compiling a rust project for ARM. It compiles perfectly for x86, but whenever I switch to an ARM target it can't find the Openssl installation, I have pkg-config installed and working so its not that error. Not sure how to set the OPENSSL_DIR variable successfully either or where to find the installation myself. The error is pasted fully below

```html
error: failed to run custom build command for `openssl-sys v0.9.61`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/bob/yagna/blueberry/debug/build/openssl-sys-aae22c7790b14724/build-script-main` (exit code: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rustc-cfg=const_fn
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=ARMV7_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNUEABIHF_OPENSSL_LIB_DIR
  ARMV7_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNUEABIHF_OPENSSL_LIB_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_LIB_DIR
  OPENSSL_LIB_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=ARMV7_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNUEABIHF_OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR
  ARMV7_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNUEABIHF_OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR
  OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=ARMV7_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNUEABIHF_OPENSSL_DIR
  ARMV7_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNUEABIHF_OPENSSL_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_DIR
  OPENSSL_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_NO_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS_armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS_armv7_unknown_linux_gnueabihf
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_armv7_unknown_linux_gnueabihf
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_armv7_unknown_linux_gnueabihf
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  run pkg_config fail: "pkg-config has not been configured to support cross-compilation.\n\n                Install a sysroot for the target platform and configure it via\n                PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR and PKG_CONFIG_PATH, or install a\n                cross-compiling wrapper for pkg-config and set it via\n                PKG_CONFIG environment variable."

  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at '

  Could not find directory of OpenSSL installation, and this `-sys` crate cannot
  proceed without this knowledge. If OpenSSL is installed and this crate had
  trouble finding it,  you can set the `OPENSSL_DIR` environment variable for the
  compilation process.

  Make sure you also have the development packages of openssl installed.
  For example, `libssl-dev` on Ubuntu or `openssl-devel` on Fedora.

  If you're in a situation where you think the directory *should* be found
  automatically, please open a bug at https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl
  and include information about your system as well as this message.

  $HOST = x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  $TARGET = armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
  openssl-sys = 0.9.61

  ', /home/bob/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/openssl-sys-0.9.61/build/find_normal.rs:174:5
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

The .cargo config file is also as follows

```html
[build]
target-dir="/home/bob/yagna/blueberry"
target="armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf"
linker = "arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc"
[target.armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf]
linker = "arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc"
```

At a loss for what to do, this ubuntu, I have libssl-dev installed and up to date, the target is added and install using rustup and sudo apt get. Not sure how to fix this

Comment: You'll need `libssl-dev` for the target architecture.

Comment: Ok, vendoring it worked for those who come across this in the future

Comment: I would definitely not recommend vendoring OpenSSL since it has frequent security updates and unless you are very careful about updating it your code will have security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Can you explain how you vendored it @Frustrated? Thanks!

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer yes, however I will say try the other solutions or your code may quickly become vulnerable. The way to do it in your Cargo.toml is to add `openssl = { version = "0.10", features = ["vendored"] }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're compiling something with OpenSSL for `armhf`, then you'll need to have the `libssl-dev` package installed for that architecture.  That will involve setting up dpkg for it via `dpkg --add-architecture armhf` and then doing an `apt-get update` and `apt-get install libssl-dev:armhf`.

Note that it may not be possible to install multiple versions of `libssl-dev` at once, and resolving the dependencies in a way that doesn't end up removing a lot of packages may be tricky.  Debian-style multiarch is very capable, but it can be a bit fiddly at times.

You definitely should not vendor OpenSSL because it frequently comes out with security updates.  Similarly, it is also a bad idea to statically link OpenSSL.  If you do vendor or statically link it, unless you are extremely careful to keep it up to date, your code will contain security vulnerabilities.

Comment: ive tried doing this, but im getting the following error:

E: Unable to locate package libssl-dev:armhf

how do i fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately, this comment space is too small to answer that question because we'd need to see the full set of error messages you're seeing and the steps you've taken to make this work.  You'd be better off asking a new question, probably on Super User.